# How to always MOSI pin low after the stm32 spi Trasmit is over

Tags: embedded, stm32, spi

[image]

### Blue     : MOSI

### Sky Blue : CLK

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

If the last bit of MOSI Data is HIGH during SPI transmission, the next signal will continue to be HIGH. Is there any way to get it to come out as LOW after SPI transmission?

Comment: Please edit the question to not have links to images, these aren't allowed.  Also please edit the question to explain why it matters to you that the line goes low when no-one is reading it.  Finally if you can't find a better way to do it then you can change the pin back to GPIO mode after each transmission.

Comment: Do you have pull-down (or up) resistors on any of your signals? Possibly the STM32 puts the signal into a high-Z state when it is not using it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The truth if it is it probably does not matter. When all slaves are de-selected, all slave-in will be high-impedance and minimal current will be drawn. Unless you have a pull-down resistor on that line, which would be a *hardware* design error.

If you really need to however, simply clock out a single zero byte with no slave selected.  Nothing will be receiving the data, but the last bit will be guaranteed to be zero.

Alternatively you could disable the entire SPI peripheral by clearing the SPE bit in SPI_CR1.  No doubt there is some bloated overcomplicated STM32Cube HAL function to do that for you, or you could just, you know... clear it.  You need to re-enable it if course before any further transactions.

`HAL_SPI_DeInit()` will certainly do that for you but much more besides - you would have to call `HAL_SPI_Init()` again to restore it, which is somewhat heavyweight if you are using a single device or the same settings for all devices.  Internally they use `__HAL_SPI_DISABLE()` and  `__HAL_SPI_ENSABLE()` macros.

Comment: _Alternatively you could disable the entire SPI peripheral by clearing the SPE bit in SPI_CR1._ - that threestates the SPI pins, not guaranteed to pull low unless external or internal pulldown is used (against which you've warned, I don't quite understand why, is it just to decrease consumption or any other consideration?). IMO the true alternative is to switch given pin to GPIO output after SPI is done, as @Tom_V said in comment to original post.

Comment: @wek Yes, SPI does not require pull-up or down and to include them is unnecessary and potentially a current leak. The OP has not been clear on his reasoning, but I assumed some naive perception of a power advantage.  It is off-topic and I should perhaps have avoided advising. Agreed it is not guaranteed to be low, it will float. But essentially "disconnected" may be what the OP is really after.  I avoided reconfiguring to GPIO because it won't work if the GPIO config lock feature were used, and requires complete reinitialisation of the SPI for each transaction

Comment: @wek I don't know whether the SPI retains output state after SPE clear.  I suspect not; in that case, simply toggling it back to SPE set may renable it with the pin low.